# Gantt Chart for Asp.Net Web forms application

Tags: asp.net, charts

We are researching for product to use in our enterprise application based on Asp.Net Web forms.

The main points are as fellow:

Display Gantt View without the Task List.

Allow dynamic scale (Week/Month/Year)

Gantt chart will show Actions. Each Action has Planned Start date/ End Date, Forecast Start date/ End Date, Actual Start date/ End Date. We need to show each action as group. At top will be action name, below it a bar for Planned, Forecast and Actual dates.

Provide paging if data is huge.

Please let us know, if it is possible to achieve the requirement stated above.

Thks

Hafeez

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer first: this is a vendor-biased answer as I represent a company that is specialized in developing Gantt chart controls. Your above mentioned requirements can be achieved with our [Gantt chart software](http://www.netronic.com/products/varchart-xgantt/overview.html) control called VARCHART XGantt is also available as ASP.NET Edition.

Please have a look and let me know your thoughts.

If you like what you see, please send an email to sales@netronic.com and refer to this stackoverflow discussion: we are happy to prove our capabilities with a free-of-charge rapid prototype.

regards,
Martin